# Creation of default providers through Admin SDK for Google Cloud Identity Platform

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

Currently, Admin SDK docs say that programmatically I can create only SAML or OpenID Connect providers for tenants. Is there a way to create default providers through Admin SDK (Microsoft, Google)?

Comment: Could you please share this Admin SDK doc you mention?

Comment: @CarloC. here it is - https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#managing_saml_and_oidc_providers_programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can create a provider, as we can read on these documents [1] [2], but I don't see how to make it the "default", I guess that you would choose the one you created when configuring it [3].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#creating_a_provider

[2] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/managing-providers-programmatically#getting_a_saml_provider_configuration

[3] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#configuring_the_provider

Comment: No, "default" means Google, Microsoft, Facebook, etc and custom means SAML and OIDC providers. Currently, through API you can create the only custom providers

Comment: As I can read on this Document:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#managing_saml_and_oidc_providers_programmatically

"The default supported identity providers (such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, and Microsoft) cannot be configured using the Admin SDK"

I don't think there is currently a way to use the AdminSDK to do this.

You can look into opening a FR to ask for this feature to become available on the future.
https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker